# How to send message to Azure event hub with amqp using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

How to send message to Azure event hub with amqp using JMeter.
can anyone please help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download [`azure-messaging-eventhubs`  library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure/azure-messaging-eventhubs) and all its dependencies and drop them to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Restart JMeter to pick the libraries up
3. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to your Thread group
4. Write Java (or even better [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)) code implementing your scenario in the JSR223 Sampler. Example code can be found at [Use Java to send events to or receive events from Azure Event Hubs (azure-messaging-eventhubs) article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-java-get-started-send), I'll add it here just in case:

   ```
   import com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.*

   final String connectionString = 'EVENT HUBS NAMESPACE CONNECTION STRING'
   final String eventHubName = 'EVENT HUB NAME'

   // create a producer using the namespace connection string and event hub name
   EventHubProducerClient producer = new EventHubClientBuilder()
           .connectionString(connectionString, eventHubName)
           .buildProducerClient()

   // prepare a batch of events to send to the event hub
   EventDataBatch batch = producer.createBatch()
   batch.tryAdd(new EventData('First event'))
   batch.tryAdd(new EventData('Second event'))
   batch.tryAdd(new EventData('Third event'))
   batch.tryAdd(new EventData('Fourth event'))
   batch.tryAdd(new EventData('Fifth event'))

   // send the batch of events to the event hub
   producer.send(batch)

   // close the producer
   producer.close()
   ```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help.  I have tried using above option but i get below error 2021-03-05 18:12:06,250 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: EventHubPOC 1-1
2021-03-05 18:12:06,278 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: EventHubPOC 1-1
2021-03-05 18:12:06,279 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[EventHubPOC 1-1,6,main]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/azure/core/amqp/implementation/TokenManagerProvider

Comment: I don't know what you tried, the very first point states and **all its dependencies**, should I use online translation tool to convert it into your native language?

Comment: Hi Dmitir, based on the error that i saw in JMeter log files. i have downloaded jar files but got stuck at below error. Could not get jar file for this java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ConnectionStringProperties.getSharedAccessSignature()'